# What is the song when Luffy starts to explore the Gray Terminal in episode 494?

Tags: one-piece, music

In episode 494 around 7:47, there's a song playing when Luffy starts to explore the Gray Terminal.

What is that song?

Answer (score 1):

This song is called *Heey!* from *One Piece Movie 5*.

Comment: I have removed the link to the illegal steam site. in future please refer to [this list](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587) for legal sites to link to

Comment: In case anyone wondering if this is a correct answer or not: yes, this is the correct answer. The lack of reference is because I removed the dead YouTube link (and unnecessary episode link)